“Server Component Error” When Using "use client" in Next.js and Medusa.js Project
I'm working on an e-commerce project using Next.js and Medusa.js, and I'm encountering a "Server Component Error" when I add "use client" to a component. I need this directive for client-side interactivity, such as using useState and useEffect, but the error prevents proper client-side rendering.
// pages/product.js
"use client";

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Product = ({ product }) => {
    const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Fetch additional product details, simulating an API call
        console.log('Fetching additional details...');
    }, []);

    const handleAddToCart = () => {
        // Add to cart logic
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{product.name}</h1>
            <p>{product.description}</p>
            <input
                type="number"
                value={quantity}
                onChange={(e) => setQuantity(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button onClick={handleAddToCart}>Add to Cart</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Product;


I added "use client"; at the top of the file to enable client-side rendering, but this results in a "Server Component Error."

Moving Product into pages/product.js directly seems to implicitly treat it as a server component.

I’ve reviewed the Next.js documentation on Server and Client Components, but I’m unsure how to structure this component to avoid the error.



double check use client directive ,but make sure it's not in a subdirectory that defaults to server components.
if u use product component with another product compnts ,ensure that the parent component is also a client component if it needs to render Product.
check react compatible
